# Get sensor values Ubuntu Touch

Tags: qt, ubuntu, sensors, ubuntu-touch

I'm new to Ubuntu applications and I'm trying to make an application for Ubuntu Touch that reads the values from the sensors (Accelerometer, Gyroscope,...) but I don't know where to begin. Which language to use? QML, C++.. I've done a thorough search around the web and I couldn't find a single sample application using sensors in ubuntu touch.

I've tried to use QtMobility and the QtSensors plugin with QtCreator but it only runs the code on the desktop. When I try to run the app on the device a message saying that the modules are not installed appears. So, I don't know if QtSensors is implemented in Ubuntu Touch or even if this is the right way to access sensors in Ubuntu touch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sensor reading is still work in progress in Ubuntu Touch.

If you're interested in following the progress of this and other features, you might want to check out the [Ubuntu SDK features status page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/SdkFeatureStatus).

That page documents the status of the planned features to be added to the Ubuntu platform on mobile devices and when they will be accessible via the Ubuntu SDK for app developers to use it in their applications.

- **Tracking progress**: If you are interested in a particular feature, please subscribe to the corresponding blueprint in the table to get e-mail notifications when the work items update.
- **Keeping up to date**: To stay up to date about the development of Ubuntu Touch and to ask any questions, [subscribe to the Ubuntu Phone mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone).

You might also want to ask your Ubuntu Touch related questions on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).